# How do I get a JTextFields Action Command?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a jTextField which I set a command String however I want to be able to retrieved it **without** having to trigger an event.

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setActionCommand("command");

String cmd = tf.getActionCommand();  <----   ???????
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: The action command string that I set. On a JButton you have .setActionCommand and .getActionCommand to set and get the action command string but with JTextField there is only a setActionCommand. I know you can get a JTextField's action command string by triggering an event but I want it without having to do this.

Comment: The obvious question is of course why would you want this. What possible use-case requires this. That aside, you could consider using the `putClientProperty` and `getClientProperty` methods that every `JComponent` has for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, JTextField does not provide getActionCommand().

Take a look at:

[Uses of getActionCommand()](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/awt/event/ActionEvent/getActionCommand%28%29.html)